# how do you write a program for function named makeWordLengthDict which takes a LIST of words as its only parameter, and returns a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I was trying to write the code for function named makeWordLengthDict which takes a LIST of words as its only parameter, and returns a dictionary that maps each word to the number of characters in that word. can anyone help me how to start it with?

Comment: You said your were trying. Does that mean you must have some sort of idea? Do you have pseudocode? Or do you have some code. Please share either one.

Comment: Start with a Python tutorial. Pay attention to the use of list and dicts in particular. Sorry, but SO is *not* a replacement for regular learning, it can't teach stuff from scratch and it doesn't want to. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

A simple dictionary comprehension would do this:

```
def makeWordLengthDict(list_of_words):
    return {i:len(i) for i in list_of_words}
```

If the function is called passing `["ball","cat"]` as the argument then the function will return: `{'ball': 4, 'cat': 3}`

Answer (score -1):

I thought I should post the second code before you ask. So here you go buddy...

```
words_list = ["Apple", "Banana", "Ball", "Cat", "Bat", "Rat"] # Only Rat will be update in the Dictionary

def makeWordLengthDict(words):
    keys = [len(word) for word in words]
    words = [word for word in words]

    return(keys, words)

keys, words = makeWordLengthDict(words_list)

# To access them accordingly.
for i in range(len(words_list)):
    print(f"{keys[i]}: {words[i]}")
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit this into your original answer?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score -2):

The code works but there is a problem with this concept. If you have two words of the same length, only one of them will be updated to the dictionary(The last one only). Because a dictionary can't have more than one item with the same key. Running the code I've provided will show you the problem. But you can do one thing if you find a length that is repeated, you can name them as 3a for another string in the list with 3 characters. But this might sound a bit inappropriate, so you can use two lists. One will act as the key of the dictionary and the other one as the value for that key. Reply "Second Code" if you want the second one.

```
words_list = ["Apple", "Banana", "Ball", "Cat", "Bat", "Rat"] # Only Rat will be update in the Dictionary

def makeWordLengthDict(words):
    word_dict = {}
    for word in words:
        length = len(word)
        word_dict.update({length: word})

    return(word_dict)

print(makeWordLengthDict(words_list))
```